# How to use LTRIM AND RTRIM in SQL Server to trim leading zeros except 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this string:

```
000001111
```

I need answer like `01111` by using `ltrim` and `rtrim`.

OR: what input can produce such an answer? But only using `ltrim` and `rtrim`.

Comment: You can't use `LTRIM` for this because `LTRIM` only removes leading whitespace, not zero characters.

Comment: Please provide some other sample inputs and the corresponding desired outputs.  For example, what do you want for an input of '0000000002'?  or '1234567890'?  or '00000000000'?  or 'John Smith'?

Comment: @Brian I don't think the OP is trying to get a desired output.   See his second comment to my answer below.   I think OP is trying to get an explanation for a result he thinks he got.

Comment: Well, I don't have time to try to guess what the OP is really asking.

Comment: @Tab Yes true! I just wanted to know the explanation for the output I Got! Thanks tab.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get `01111` from `000001111` using ONLY `ltrim` and `rtrim`.

EDIT:   The result you claim to have gotten in your comment is not reproducible.

When I execute:

```
SELECT CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM('000001111')) AS INT)
```

The result I get is `1111`

Comment: Any special character in between the string can pick it from 01111?

Comment: @user9208802 I don't understand your question in the comment above.

Comment: 000001111 Is a string. I need 01111 as INT.      I have used CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM('000001111') AS INT). So my answer should be 1111. But I got 01111! I don't know why I received this answer! So I'm trying to recreate such a scenario!  TELL ME HOW CAN I BRING 01111 JUST BY USING LTRIM AND RTRIM.. NOTE: Input can be anything but I need 01111 as answer.

Comment: It is not possible to get `01111` as an INT.   INT cannot have leading zeros.

Comment: Input is a string! So even that cannot bring a leading zero?

Comment: No, when you cast it to an INT, the leading zero cannot possibly be retained no matter what the input was.

Comment: Go on. I'm dying to see this. You post up a **screenshot** of your SQL Server Managment Studio running a query that contains only LTRIM, RTRIM and '00001111', a result of 01111 in the grid, and I'll tell you how come it did it